# webapi call to nodejs to postgres with multiple placeholders not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have two tables recipemaster and ingredientmaster.

### recipemaster table

```
recipe_code |recipe_title |
------------|-------------|
1           |    one      |
2           |    two      |
3           |    three    |
4           |    four     |
```

### ingredientmaster table

```
ingredient_code |recipe_code |ingredient_detail |
----------------|------------|------------------|
                |            |                  |
```

In front end react, i am entering ingredient_detail based on the selected recipe_title from the recipemaster table using select box, my task is to select recipe_title from recipemaster table and that should select the particular recipe_code based on the recipe_title and populate that particular recipe_code in the ingredientmaster table. Ofcourse ingredient_detail is also entered together. Ingredient_code is auto incremented, so no need to worry about that.

what i tried :-

```
app.post('/api/new-ingre',function(request,response){
    console.log('Ingredients connected to db')
    var recipe_code;
    var recipe_title = request.body.recipe_title;
    var recipe_text = request.body.recipe_text;
    let values = [recipe_title,recipe_text];
    pool.connect((err,db,done)=>{
        if(err){
            return response.status(400).send(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(request.body.recipe_title)
            console.log(request.body.recipe_text)
            db.query('INSERT INTO public.ingredientmaster(recipe_code,ingredient_detail=?) select recipe_code from recipemaster where recipe_title = ?',[recipe_text,recipe_title],(err,table)=>{
                done();
                if(err){
                    return response.status(400).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    console.log('INGREDIENT DATA INSERTED');
                    response.status(201).send({message:'Ingredient data inserted'});
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

The query works when executed in database. But i dont know how to use this query in nodejs when this type of complex query comes.
 Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What database and library are you using?

Comment: Postgres and npm library , fetch request

Comment: Try using `$1` and `$2` as placeholders then

Comment: i did that also, but not worked

Comment: Why don't you use an ORM? And the routers should not content any business logic or database transactions.

Comment: Can you add the code where you require other modules? I take it `app` is from express.js, but is `pool` and `db` from [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)? That would help to know.

Comment: What are you really asking? The query works .. so it's not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had similar problems at the beging of my implementation and it is because I didn't had enough understanding about  postgres, so my advise is:

1. I'm using pg-promise library
2. Create a connect singleton file like this (mydb.js)

   ```
   'use strict';
   let pgp = require('pg-promise')();
   //let db = pgp(config.postgres);
   module.exports.db = db;
   ```
3. Connect to PostgreSQL on you app.js (or equivalent main file) using previous file, something like this:

   ```
   import { db } from './mydb';
   //.... more imports and initialization lines
   //....
   //I use this to validate postgres connection only on app.js
   db.proc('version')
   .then(() => {
     console.log('Postgres Connected.... ');
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log('Postgres connection error:');
     console.error(err);
     process.exit(-1);
   });
   ```
4. On your controller use this code or similar:

   ```
   import { db } from './mydb';
   //...more code
   app.post('/api/new-ingre',function(request,response){
      let sqlInsert = `INSERT INTO ......`;
      db.any(sqlInsert, [])
      .then(()=>{
          console.log('INGREDIENT DATA INSERTED');
          response.status(201).send({message:'Ingredient data inserted'});
       })
      .catch((err)=>{
          response.status(400).send(err);
      })
   });
   ```